# UIImageView with mode Scale To Fill displays strange image

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am new in iOS. I have added `UIImageView` in `UITableViewCell`. I set `imagewidth` = 1/6 screen width and `imageheight` = 5/3 width then I add an default photo to the `imageview`.
I want the photo will fill the `imageview` so I choose mode `ScaleToFill` but the `imageview` displays strange.

Here is the image if I set mode `Aspect Fit`
[image: 123]

Here is the image if I set mode `Scale To Fill`

[image: 123]

I have tested with another image but it has the same problem.
I test on X-Code 7.1, simulator IPad2 /IOS 9.1.
Anyone can give me some ideas to solve this problem.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Based on image it will take.... if your image is small like 100X100.. but you're tableviwecell imageview 100 X 200... it's looks bad....

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but I don't care about the image quality, I just want it fill uiimageview.